# How do I sort by a dictionary's keys in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Say I have a dictionary:

```
1 -2 -1 ! 3 4 5
```

How do I sort it based on the keys (rather than the values, which seems to be what `asc` does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do as follows:

```
d:(1;2;-1)!(3;4;5);
d:(asc key d)#d;
d
 -1| 5
 1 | 3
 2 | 4
```